# installing sbcl on cygwin

Tags: lisp, cygwin, sbcl

Anyone know how to install SBCL binaries on cygwin?

I ask since I think the standard instructions are broken. See, I followed the instructions at http://www.sbcl.org/platform-table.html and had the following problems:

- the "compile from source" option needs gnumake and gnumale is not a cygwin package
- the other options lead to crashes (some strange image file not found or sbcl.exe not found)

So rather than fight thru all that, my planB is just to grab a binary.

Anyone know where one can be found?

t

Answer (score 1):

SBCL/win32 is not a cygwin binary, last time I checked, but a normal win32 application. So just download the binary, quite possibly the unofficial one (as there aren't enough win32 developers to work on windows port).

Building it from scratch might be a bit problematic, especially when you add Cygwin into the mix.